# Send UDP packet to ESP8266 from Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to send a UDP packet from Python to a ESP8266 on my local network. The esp successfully connects to my AP, but does not receive any packets. I can get the ESP to serve a web page, so there shouldn't be any problems with the communication between my computer and the ESP.

This is the code I'm using on my computer to send the packets:

```python
import socket
from time import sleep

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

while 1:
    sock.sendto("hello".encode(), ( "192.168.43.150", 5007 ))
    print("sent message")
    sleep(0.1)
```

and I'm using this on the ESP:

```cpp
/*
 * 31 mar 2015
 * This sketch display UDP packets coming from an UDP client.
 * On a Mac the NC command can be used to send UDP. (nc -u 192.168.1.101 2390). 
 *
 * Configuration : Enter the ssid and password of your Wifi AP. Enter the port number your server is listening on.
 *
 */

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUDP.h>

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
const char* ssid = "***********";  //  your network SSID (name)
const char* pass = "**********";       // your network password

unsigned int localPort = 5007;      // local port to listen for UDP packets

byte packetBuffer[512]; //buffer to hold incoming and outgoing packets

// A UDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // setting up Station AP
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

  // Wait for connect to AP
  Serial.print("[Connecting]");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  int tries=0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    tries++;
    if (tries > 30){
      break;
    }
  }
  Serial.println();


printWifiStatus();

  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  Serial.print("Udp server started at port ");
  Serial.println(localPort);
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop()
{
  int noBytes = Udp.parsePacket();
  if ( noBytes ) {
    Serial.print(millis() / 1000);
    Serial.print(":Packet of ");
    Serial.print(noBytes);
    Serial.print(" received from ");
    Serial.print(Udp.remoteIP());
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());
    // We've received a packet, read the data from it
    Udp.read(packetBuffer,noBytes); // read the packet into the buffer

    // display the packet contents in HEX
    for (int i=1;i<=noBytes;i++){
      Serial.print(packetBuffer[i-1],HEX);
      if (i % 32 == 0){
        Serial.println();
      }
      else Serial.print(' ');
    } // end for
    Serial.println();
  } // end if


}

void printWifiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);
}
```

The Python code can successfully send UDP packets to another Python script, so the problem should be on the ESP side.

What can I do to debug this?

Comment: What version of the arduino software are you using to communicate with the esp board?